# tracking number field in Woocommerce order

Tags: php, custom-field, woocommerce-offtopic

I am creating a custom field `Tracking_ID` on Woocommerce, where the admin will enter the tracking ID as value.

How can i get the value of the created custom field and display it inside the `customer-completed-order.php`

Also (Optional) i want to show the tracking ID field in the user's `track-order` order page in his/her my-account.

**Woocommerce>order field:**

[image]

**oceanwp-child/woocommerce/emails/customer-completed-order.php**

```
<?php /* translators: %s: Customer first name */ ?>
<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Hi %s,', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $order->get_billing_first_name() ) ); ?></p>
<?php /* translators: %s: Site title */ ?>
<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Your %s order is completed. Your tracking number is: {$fld}', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( wp_specialchars_decode( get_option( 'blogname' ), ENT_QUOTES ) ) ); ?></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Melissa's answer, here is what i did and it worked for me.

```
    <?php
    #Tracking ID

    $tracking_id = get_post_meta($order->get_order_number(), 'Tracking_ID', true);

    if( ! empty($tracking_id) )
    { ?>
<p> <?php
printf( esc_html__( 'Your tracking number is: %s', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html($tracking_id)  );?> 
</p> <?php 
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax to get your custom field is:

```
get_post_meta($post_id, $key, $single);
```

In your context, you should try:

```
$tracking_id = get_post_meta($order->get_order_number(), 'Tracking_ID', true);
```

To show you in your example:

```
<?php /* translators: %s: Site title */ 
$tracking_id = get_post_meta($order->get_order_number(), 'Tracking_ID', true); ?>
<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Your %s order is completed. Your tracking number is: %s', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( wp_specialchars_decode( get_option( 'blogname' ), esc_html($tracking_id) ) ) ); ?></p>
```